# Get Summary statistics by column in R and put in a table

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the `attitude` data frame. I want to get 11 different measures of central tendancy and put them in a table that looks like so:

```
Central_Meaures Ratings_Measure ...
mean            65.23
median          55.2
...             ...
cor()           0.5
```

I made my table like so:

```
cntrl_measures <- c(
  'mean'
  ,'median'
  ,'mode'
  ,'max'
  ,'min'
  ,'range'
  ,'quantile'
  ,'IQR'
  ,'var()'
  ,'sd()'
  ,'cor()'
)
ratings_measure <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)
priv_measure <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)
learn_measure <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)
raise_measure <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)
critical_measrue <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)
advance_measure <- c(
  '','','','','','','','','','',''
)

measure.dataframe <- data.frame(cntrl_measures,
                                ratings_measure,
                                priv_measure,
                                learn_measure,
                                raise_measure,
                                critical_measrue,
                                advance_measure)
```

Thinking maybe a for loop would work?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: and how to you want to deal with measures that return more than 1 value like `range`? also `cor()` doesn't work on a single column. So which correlations do you want to catch?

Comment: I see, I'll have to go think about this a bit more